# Simple.Data in ASP.NET Core - 'No Ado Provider found.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, simple.data

To my application in ASP.NET Core I have added from nuget - Simple.Data.SqlServer.

And in my Code: `var db = Database.Open();` in this line I recives an error: "**No Ado Provider found**"

I assume that it's because my Startup.cs (file is in different project.) Anyway there I have:

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), 
b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Aps.API")));
```

So I was trying to change my db variable to:

```
var db = Database.OpenConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
Catalog=DataDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;");`
```

Still the same problem.

Comment: This could have been a temporary bug in the Core version of Simple.Data. It should have been fixed now.

Comment: According to https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data/issues/389, there is no support of .net core.